# equivalent encryption/decryption functions on C++ linux and C# windows

Tags: c#, .net, c++, linux

i have both a web gui written in C#, running on IIS server and C++ written engine, running on apache.
i need my web gui to encrypt and the C++ engine to decrypt the data.
what equivalent function can i use to achieve my purpose ?

Comment: http://www.cryptopp.com/

Comment: I'm not at all certain why you would need your GUI to encrypt anything. This is what HTTPS is for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MD% since it is built in to the .NET Framework to encript

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Value);
data = x.ComputeHash(data);
return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

and then use an open-source component for C++ as described at 
http://userpages.umbc.edu/~mabzug1/cs/md5/md5.html

to decript.
Good luck